# How Can I add an Animation to this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to add an animation to 3 divs when page is loading.

When the page is loading these 3 circles should be come from right being animating.

This is my HTML -

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="div1"></div>           
        <div id="div2"></div>           
        <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is [My FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AEgqv/) with HTML and CSS

Can anybody help me to add an animation to this using jQuery.

Comment: Please try something.  We don't commonly give you 'free' code.  You have to at least try something first..

Comment: I agree, also it would be nice to know where it is animating from, other than just right.  Are they of the screen to the right, should they start on top of each other?  Please give more info.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no need for JavaScript/ jQuery here.

Just use CSS3 and you will be fine.

Check the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/AEgqv/1/)**

**CSS**

```
/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.fade-in.two {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.fade-in.three {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
```

**HTML** *(added classes)*

```
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="div1" class="fade-in one"></div>           
            <div id="div2" class="fade-in two"></div>           
            <div id="div3" class="fade-in three"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are numerous animations you can do with CSS...if you don't like the fade in you can pick some other animations or even combine a couple (different animation to each div)

**[jQuery Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/AEgqv/2/)** as well

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am looking for an animation something similar to this -http://builder.hypesalons.com/builder/users/2001070/index.html

Comment: Maybe you should have said this on your original post? As i told you it's up to you what animation you will use. http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp Here you can get a couple of things

Comment: can we add like jquery easing using css3?

Comment: @Thanos +1 spot on mate, CSS3 alone is enough for this case, but my concern is about IE<9. Do animations work there? I think not.

Comment: @TNK Do you need to support IE<=9? I don't think CSS3 animations work in them. Check for browser support. Also, I am going to post another CSS3 version as answer, check if it matches your needs.

Comment: You can have a look at : http://caniuse.com/css-animation for browser compatibility of CSS3 Animation

Comment: Thanks:) so looks like IE <= 9 does not support them :(

Comment: I really don't like jQuery for animations... but here is a simple example of that http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/AEgqv/2/

Comment: nice.. Thanos, Can I know, is it possible to add jquery easing effect to this animation. Eg: 'easeOutBounce' etc...

Comment: Yeah definitely. You can add any type of animation you want. Just have a look on this demo here http://ralphwhitbeck.com/demo/jquery-ui-easing-effects-demo-and-documentation/  which will provide you with source code and demos for all the jQuery animations

Answer (score 1):

use jquery animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/. call your JavaScript function on document ready state

Comment: can you tell me how can I use it?